# Pass a Struct to String.Format as args

Tags: c#, string, struct

Is it possible use a struct as arguments for a `string.Format` like this:

```
struct kid
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
};

kid.name = alice;
kid.age = 2;

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Her name is {0} and she's {1} years old", kid));
```

instead of this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Her name is {0} and she's {1} years old", kid.name ,kid.age));
```

Edit:

The string will be read at runtime from a configuration file

Comment: No.  {0} and {1} are two different properties which you cannot get from one object 'kid'.

Comment: As a side note, for Console.WriteLine you do not need to use string.Format as the WriteLine method performs the same action and accepts parameters in the same way.

Comment: Theoretically one could create an indexer in a struct as well as in a class (if I remember correctly) and then maybe it should be equivalent to a string array... Now I don't have a compiler to validate this as an answer

Comment: Can you override `ToString()` in the struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.Format` has a signature of `String.Format(string format, params object[] args)` you can convert your struct into an object array.

```
struct Kid
{
    public string name;
    public int age;

    public object[] ToObjectArray()
    {
        return new object[] {
            name, age };
    }
    public static implicit operator object[](Kid kid)
    {
        return kid.ToObjectArray();
    }
};

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Kid kid=new Kid() { name="alice", age=2 };

        Console.WriteLine("Her name is {0} and she's {1} years old", kid);
        // Same as
        // Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Her name is {0} and she's {1} years old", kid));
    }
}
```

You could also take advantage of covariance and implicitly convert a `string[]` into `object[]` with

```
    public string[] ToStringArray()
    {
        return new string[] {
            name, age.ToString() };
    }
    public static implicit operator object[](Kid kid)
    {
        return kid.ToStringArray();
    }
```

instead of `ToObjectArray()`

Comment: Great, I was trying to get there but it was too difficult being on mobile with an online compiler ))

Answer (score 7):

No. How will it know what property to put where?

What you can do instead of typing the `string.Format` in such way is use c# 6.0 string interpolation and write it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Her name is {kid.name} and she's {kid.age} years old");
```

And maybe override the `ToString()` to return it:

```
struct kid
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
       return $"Her name is {name} and she's {age} years old";
    }
}
```

And then call `Console.WriteLine(kid.ToString());`

Comment: Hey, go answer Linq questions. Leave string interpolation to me :)

Comment: @uteist - hahah :) well.. was washing dishes and suddenly saw that question. Could not resist

Comment: I thing for code clarity i will go with this idea thanks

Comment: @ArnonHadas - Glad to hear :)

Comment: this can only work at compile time i need the string to be able to change at runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `IFormattable` interface by your structure and provide access to different properties by format string:

```
struct kid : IFormattable {
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public override string ToString() => ToString(null, null);
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider) {
        switch(format) {
            case null:
            case "":
                return string.Format(provider, "({0:name}, {0:age})", this);
            case "name":
                return name.ToString(provider);
            case "age":
                return age.ToString(provider);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(format));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write it as following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Her name is {0:name} and she's {0:age} years old", kid);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is possible is accessing a struct as an array so:

If kid is a struct kidStr, then kid[0] and kid[1] could be defined as name and age.ToString() and used as a couple of parameters in the WriteLine... should that make sense to you...

```
public string this[int i] { 
    get { return i == 0 ? name :  age. ToString(); }
}
```

or more simply

```
public string[] ToArray() {
    return new string[2]{ name, age.ToString()};
}
```

having the above indexer in the struct kidStr and an instance kid

```
Console.WriteLine("name is {0}, age is {1}", kid[0], kid[1]); // or kid.ToArray()
```